# SELECT a variable defined with WITH

Tags: postgresql

I have

```
with
s1 as (select serial from wingstatushref where href = ? for key share),
i1 as (insert into wingstatushref
select ?
where not exists(select * from s1)
on conflict (href) do update set href=? returning serial)
```

which uses the same ? three times. I tried integrating the ? into the with:

```
with
h as (values (?)),
s1 as (select serial from wingstatushref where href=h for key share),
i1 as (insert into wingstatushref
select h
where not exists(select * from s1)
on conflict (href) do update set href=h returning serial)
select serial from s1 union all select serial from i1;
```

But that gives me

```
x SQL Compiles and Typechecks
 x ERROR: column "h" does not exist
  Position: 83 (specs2.scala:64)
```

What's the correct way to reference the data in h from the select clause?

Comment: `h` is a c CTE name, syntactically identical to a table name or correlation name/alias. you'll have to indicate which field(s) from `h` you want: `SELECT h.field from h ...`. So you'll have to supply a field name to the `VALUES` cte. (also: `serial` doesn't look like a column name to me...)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RhodiumToad from #postgresql

```
with
  h(hr) as (values (?)),
  s1 as (select serial from h, wingstatushref where href=h.hr for key share),
  i1 as (insert into wingstatushref
    select hr from h
    where not exists(select * from s1)
    on conflict (href) do update set href=wingstatushref.href where EXCLUDED.href=wingstatushref.href returning serial)
  select serial from s1 union all select serial from i1;
```